# dotnet Core on ARM Cortex-A5 - "Illegal Instruction"

Tags: c#, .net-core, embedded-linux

I have an Atmel dev kit, with an ARM Cortex-A5 processor in it. I have an application written for dotnet core that I need to run on it. I have successfully got Ubuntu 16.04 running on it ([which I set up from these instructions](http://www.eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/SAMA5D3)).

As a comparison point, I've tried setting up and running a "hello world" dotnet example on a Raspberry Pi - this works fine. But, using the same steps on the Atmel board it always crashes with `Illegal Instruction`, and no further information.

I have downloaded the `armhf` binary for dotnet from the download page: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/, and have tried both the 2.0.5 stable release and the 2.1.0 preview, both give the same result.

I've made the [simple example from the Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu), then prepared it for Linux-ARM on my host machine with `dotnet publish -r linux-arm`. When I move the output to the dev board and try to run it, I get this:

```
$ dotnet --info

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.0-preview2-26226-02
  Commit:  40177995a6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

The.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-preview2-26226-02 [/home/ubuntu/dotnet/shared]

$ dotnet myApp.dll 
Illegal instruction
```

Is there something I need to do for dotnet core on this ARM device? Or is this a bug that I should file?

Comment: Whether this is a bug or not, I think creating a GitHub issue has the best chance of getting you an answer.

Comment: I've got an ARM Cortex-A9 dev kit that I was also able to run the code on - it worked on the A9. So, perhaps there's something about the instruction set available to the A5 that dotnet doesn't like.